# Sympy solve function giving an incorrect solutions/not meeting parameters

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to have sympy help in solving a large system of equations for the behavior of a beam under a unique loading situation. When I have sympy solve for the unknowns it runs with no error warnings however when I reinput the solved variables the outputs do not satisfy the system of equations I set.

I do not know what could be causing this since there are almost no steps taken after solving

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
#lots of setup
E = 30*10**9 
I = 5.5*10**9/(1000**4)
w1 = 30000
p1 = 200000
ma = 90000
p2 = 15000
x,r1,m,r2,r3,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8 = symbols('x,r1,m,r2,r3,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8')
m1 = -m+r1*x-(-w1*x**3/36+w1*x**2/2)
t1p = integrate(m1,x)+c1
y1p = integrate(t1p,x)+c2
t1 = t1p/E/I/1.5
y1 = y1p/E/I/1.5
m2 = -m+r1*x-(w1*6/2)*(x-2)-p1*(x-6))
t2p = integrate(m2,x)+c3
y2p = integrate(t2p,x)+c4
t2 = t2p/E/I
y2 = y2p/E/I
m3 = m2+r2*(x-10)+ma
t3p = integrate(m3,x)+c5
y3p = integrate(t3p,x)+c6
t3 = t3p/E/I
y3 = y3p/E/I
m4 = m3-p2*(x-15)
t4p = integrate(m4,x)+c7
y4p = integrate(t4p,x)+c8
t4 = t4p/E/I
y4 = y4p/E/I

#Equations to be solved

eq1 = Eq(w1*6/2-p1-p2+r1+r2+r3,0)
eq2 = Eq(m-w1*6/2*2-p1*6-ma-p2*15+r2*10+r3*20,0)
eq3 = Eq(y1.subs(x,0),0)
eq4 = Eq(t1.subs(x,0),0)
eq5 = Eq(y2.subs(x,10),0)
eq6 = Eq(y4.subs(x,20),0)
eq7 = Eq(y1.subs(x,6),y2.subs(x,6))
eq8 = Eq(t1.subs(x,6),t2.subs(x,6))
eq9 = Eq(y2.subs(x,10),y3.subs(x,10))
eq10 = Eq(t2.subs(x,10),t3.subs(x,10))
eq11 = Eq(y3.subs(x,15),y4.subs(x,15))
eq12 = Eq(t3.subs(x,15),t4.subs(x,15))
sol = solve((eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8,eq9,eq10,eq11,eq12),(r1,m,r2,r3,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8))
# print(sol)
# print(y1)
# print(y2)
# print(y3)
# print(y4)
# m1 = m1.subs({m:sol[m], r1:sol[r1]})
# m2 = m2.subs({m:sol[m], r1:sol[r1]})
# m3 = m3.subs({m:sol[m], r1:sol[r1], r2:sol[r2]})
# m4 = m4.subs({m:sol[m], r1:sol[r1], r2:sol[r2]})
# y1 = y1.subs({m:sol[m], r1:sol[r1], c1:sol[c1], c2:sol[c2]})
y2 = y2.subs({m:sol[m], r1:sol[r1], c3:sol[c3], c4:sol[c4]})
# y3 = y3.subs({m:sol[m], r1:sol[r1], r2:sol[r2], c5:sol[c5], c6:sol[c6]})
y4 = y4.subs({m:sol[m], r1:sol[r1], r2:sol[r2], c7:sol[c7], c8:sol[c8]})

#check parameters are satisfied
print(y2.subs(x,10),y4.subs(x,20))
```

When I plot the y1, y2, y3, and y4 I get the following

Comment: The output I see from subs is `8.88178419700125e-16 -7.10542735760100e-15`. Those are very small numbers, basically zero. If you don't use floats you'll get exactly zero.

Comment: I usually run my code in jupyter notebook and when I run the code the two outputs are '-0.0342149182401609 -0.165684836145271'. However I just tried running the code in google colab and I was getting the near-zero values that you mentioned above. Do you have any idea why this would be the case? I have never had issues with jupyter notebook in the two years I've used it.

Comment: I would be surprised if Jupyter has anything to do with it. Most likely it is because of different SymPy versions. Perhaps you are seeing a bug in an older version of SymPy.

Comment: That seems like exactly what the issue was, thank you for the help.

I was having some trouble installing new versions of sympy but I just got it to work. The version of SymPy that was installed was 1.4, I installed 1.10.1 and it is giving me the correct output now. If anyone is having similar issues, what worked for me was: !pip install --upgrade sympy

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the definition of `m2` (which I added). When you are working with SymPy, any time you write something like `3/2` you create a float because that is how Python works. But if you type the same after a SymPy object, like `x*3/2` you will get exactly `3*x/2` instead of `1.5*x`. So, basically, whenever you have an expression that is entered as operations of numbers you have to treat something like a SymPy object to avoid getting into "float mode". For your system, defining the following is sufficient:

```py
from sympy import S
E = S(30)*10**9 
I = 11*10**9/S(1000**4)/2
w1 = S(30000)
...
```

Then, as Oscar points out, you will get an exact solution which will exactly satisfy your original equations. The solution is:

```py
>>> sol
{r1: -26424250/263, m: -113651500/263, r2: 62654850/263, r3: -3355600/263, c1: 0, c2: 0, c3: 872411250/263, c4: -1411312500/263, c5: 3768453750/263, c6: -10670287500/263, c7: 3324641250/263, c8: -8451225000/263}
```

Comment: I usually run my code in jupyter notebook and when I run the code the two outputs are '-0.0342149182401609 -0.165684836145271'. However I just tried running the code in google colab and I was getting the near-zero values that you mentioned above. Do you have any idea why this would be the case?